# Qt: How to stream data over a singlepart HTTP request in realtime?

Tags: c++, qt, http, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest

I have to stream data over a singlepart HTTP request in real time. The targeted device only handle data when request is like:

```
POST ...
Content-Type:...
Content-Length:9999999
Connection:Keep-Alive
Cache-Control:no-cache
Authorization:...

<data>
<data>
<data>
...
```

In Java, I have to do some hack to make it works using the `setFixedLengthStreamingMode(9999999);` function on my `HttpURLConnection` object. Then I create the request and populate body data with a `BufferedOutputStream` object.

Now, I'm trying to develop a Qt based application to transmit data to this device but I can't achieve it. I tried something like:

```
QNetworkRequest networkRequest;
networkRequest.setUrl(/*...*/);
// Set some headers
networkRequest.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, "9999999");

QIODevice* pIoDevice = new QBuffer(this);
pIoDevice->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

QNetworkAccessManager* pNetworkAccessManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
pNetworkAccessManager->post(networkRequest, pIoDevice);

// Then exec current run loop to wait until I manually stop it.
```

On a other hand, when my producer give me data to transmit I's like to made something like:

```
pIoDeviceData->write(/* data */);
```

Problem is that reading network traces (using Wireshark), I see that the `Content-Length` emitted is equal to `0` so the device closes the connection and I get an error code `NetworkError::RemoteHostClosedError`; So I missed something but what? Any idea?

Comment: Did you set the Content-Type anywhere?

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky Yes but it has no effect at all.

Comment: I assume Qt figures out the size on its own and overwrites everything you set to actually submit the correct content length (which is 0 given an empty buffer). You could probably subclass QIODevice and return the size that you intent, fooling the network access manager this way.